# How to exclude the element from .bind()?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

This is example http://jsfiddle.net/4BjVv/6/

```
$(function(){
    $('ul#crumbs li a').bind('click',crumbClick)
});

function crumbClick(){
    $('ul#crumbs .selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parents('li').addClass('selected');
    return false;
}
```

The place and styling of The first item of list which is "Home" should be fixed

```
<ul id="crumbs">
   <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li class="selected"><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Flash</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>   
</ul>
```

I want to keep first `<li>` static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `:not()`

```
$(function(){
    $('ul#crumbs li:not(.home) a').bind('click',crumbClick)
});
```

## [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/4BjVv/7/)

based on comments below, it's just a matter of css styling...

change

```
ul#crumbs li.selected {float:left;}
```

to

```
ul#crumbs li.home,
ul#crumbs li.selected {float:left;}
```

Comment: +1, except I think you should include a link to the updated fiddle.  Oh wait, there it is! :p

Comment: Thanks. I want to keep "Home" at first place , always.

Comment: +1 Oh it was CSS part. I forgot that . Great Reigel. Great help

Answer (score 2):

Use the [greater than selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/):

```
$('ul#crumbs li:gt(0) a').bind('click',crumbClick);
```

Or alternatively, the [not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$('ul#crumbs li:not(.home) a').bind('click',crumbClick);
```